# Does applying a 2dsphere index on a mongoose schema force the location field to be required?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema and model defined as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
      email: {
        index: {
          sparse: true,
          unique: true
        },
        lowercase: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        type: String
      },
      location: {
        index: '2dsphere',
        type: [Number]
      }
    })
  , User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', Schema);
```

If I attempt:

```
var user = new User({ email: 'user@example.com' });

user.save(function(err) {
  if (err) return done(err);

  should.not.exist(err);
  done();
});
```

I receive the error message:

```
MongoError: Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?:{}
```

Despite the location field in this schema not being required, it seems to be acting as such anyways. I have tried adding `default: [0,0]` which does circumvent this error, however it seems like a bit of a hack, as this is clearly not a good default, and ideally the schema would not require the user to have a location at all times.

Do geospatial indexes with MongoDB / mongoose imply that the field being indexed is required?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For mongoose 3.8.12, you set the default value:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point'],
      default: 'Point',
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      default: [0, 0],
    }
  }
});

UserSchema.index({location: '2dsphere'});
```

Comment: Just tested with `default: undefined` on type and coordinates, it works as well.

Comment: @Tom like that :
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point'],
      default: undefined,
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      default: undefined,
    }

Comment: the way I solved it was to put index: "2dsphere" on coordinates

Comment: How the entry will comes in your collection for the property `location` ?

Answer (score 17):

By default, a property declared an array receives a default empty array to work with. MongoDB has started validating geojson fields and yells about empty arrays. The work around is to add a pre save hook to the schema that checks for this scenario and fixes up the document first.

```
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (this.isNew && Array.isArray(this.location) && 0 === this.location.length) {
    this.location = undefined;
  }
  next();
})
```

Comment: Is this something that could be added to mongoose for { type: [Number], index: '2dsphere' } fields, so it's taken care of automatically?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to create a schema with geolocation and run geospartial queries was

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["Point"], // 'location.type' must be 'Point'
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number]
    }
  }
});

UserSchema.index({location: '2dsphere'});
```

> Be careful this is important to do, the index 2dsphere in the
>   location.coordinates, if you want to run geospartial queries!

Comment: It won't let me edit this code to fix the syntax error (since its too small of an edit), but the sub-document reference needs to be surrounded in quotes. e.g. `UserSchema.index({'location.coordinates': '2dsphere'});`

Comment: the index needs to be applied to the location property, not the coordinates. : https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8644 https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8453

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have resolved this issue was changing the index type from

```
GEO:{
    type: [Number],
    index: '2dsphere'
}
```

to

```
GEO:{
    type: [Number],
    index: '2d'
}
```

It was a nightmare