# Sort and distinct in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My mongoose query is:

```
Spread.find(findCase).where('loc').near({
        center: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [self.lon, self.lat]
        },
        maxDistance: distance
}).sort({ts : -1}).distinct("postId").exec();
```

So I get the error:

```
Error: sort cannot be used with distinct
```

But if I pass the query with console

```
db.spreads.distinct({}).sort({ts: -1});
```

That is ok.

So why mongoose doesn't let me to select distinct and sort in one query and how can I do it?

Comment: Can you show us what mongoose is actually trying to execute? Just enable the debug flag `mongoose.set('debug', true)`.

Comment: Debug mode was set. The error throws in mongoose/node_modules/mquery/lib/mquery.js:2405 before logging full query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort), `sort` cannot be used with `distinct`.

> Cannot be used with distinct()

But you can perform an aggregation operation:

```
Spread.aggregate(
{$geoNear:{
  "near":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[self.lon, self.lat]},
  "distanceField":"dist.calculated",
  "maxDistance":distance,
  "query":findcase,
  "spherical": true
}},
{$sort:{"ts":-1}},
{$group:{"_id":"$postId"}},function(err,resp){
  console.log(resp);
  // handle response.
}
)
```

**Note**: A `2dsphere` Index needs to exist on the collection over the `loc` field. To create an Index, refer: [Does applying a 2dsphere index on a mongoose schema force the location field to be required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388836/does-applying-a-2dsphere-index-on-a-mongoose-schema-force-the-location-field-to).

Comment: Finally it doesn't work correctly, below I posted a test case

Answer (score 0):

Test data:

```
db.createCollection("test");

db.test.insert({
    loc : {type: 'Point', coordinates : [42,42]},
    ts : new Date(2014,2,5),
    postId : 1
});

db.test.insert({
    loc : {type: 'Point', coordinates : [42,42]},
    ts : new Date(2014,2,5),
    postId : 1
});

db.test.insert({
    loc : {type: 'Point', coordinates : [42,42]},
    ts : new Date(2014,2,4),
    postId : 2
});

db.test.insert({
    loc : {type: 'Point', coordinates : [42,42]},
    ts : new Date(2014,2,3),
    postId : 3
});
```

With query

```
db.test.aggregate([
{
    $geoNear: {
    near : { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 42, 42 ] },
    distanceField : 'dist.calculated',
    maxDistance: 200,
    spherical: true
    }
},
{
    $sort : {ts: -1}
},
{$group:{"_id":"$postId"}}
]);
```

Gives wrong result

```
{ "_id" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 1 }
```

so I guess mongo firstly applied grouping and then can't sort by absent field. For this reason probably mongoose prohibits use distinct with sorting.

Comment: You can't sort records in a single group.The code you have presented is incorrect. The sort should come before the `$group`, `$group` is just to grab the distinct values once the records are sorted.

Comment: Sorry for late answers, you mean replace group and sort in aggregate array? I did it and the result is still wrong. Or maby I don't understand something

Comment: This does not answer the question, and should be an update to your original post instead. Please only post complete solutions to the question as answers.