# mongo 2dsphere Cast to Object failed for value "[]"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using `mongoose v4.8.0`,
`mongo v3.4.1`, `node v6.9.1`

I have this this schema:

```
 var UserSchema = new Schema({
  volAddressCoords: { 'type': {type: String, default: "Point"},
  coordinates: { type: [Number],
  default: [37.9800927,23.73151580]},
  index: {type: String, default: '2dsphere'}}
  (...)
})
```

A user checks a checkbox, submits a form, and if it's false this is the req.body:

```
{ volAddress: null,
  volAddressCoords: [],
  comRange: null,
  isVolunteer: null }
```

**This is the error thrown when false (all fields are emtpy):**
*(all errors are truncated for convenience)*

```
{ ValidationError: User validation failed
errors:
   { volAddressCoords:
      { CastError: Cast to Object failed for value "[]" at path "volAddressCoords"
    message: 'Cast to Object failed for value "[]" at path "volAddressCoords"',
    name: 'CastError',
    stringValue: '"[]"',
    kind: 'Object',
    value: [],
    path: 'volAddressCoords',
    reason: undefined },
 'volAddressCoords.type':
  { ValidatorError: `,` is not a valid enum value for path `volAddressCoords.type`.
    message: '`,` is not a valid enum value for path `volAddressCoords.type`.',
    name: 'ValidatorError',
    properties: [Object],
    kind: 'enum',
    path: 'volAddressCoords.type',
    value: [Object] } },
   message: 'User validation failed',
   name: 'ValidationError' }
```

The body when true:

```
{ volAddress: '2307 Princes Highway, Heywood, Βικτώρια, Αυστραλία',
  volAddressCoords: [ 141.61755859999994, -38.1103413 ],
  comRange: 4,
  isVolunteer: true }
```

**Error when checkbox is true:**

```
{ ValidationError: User validation failed
 errors:
   { volAddressCoords:
      { CastError: Cast to Object failed for value "[ 141.61755859999994, -38.1103413 ]" at path "volAddressCoords"
message: 'Cast to Object failed for value "[ 141.61755859999994, -38.1103413 ]" at path "volAddressCoords"',
        name: 'CastError',
        stringValue: '"[ 141.61755859999994, -38.1103413 ]"',
        kind: 'Object',
        value: [Object],
        path: 'volAddressCoords',
        reason: undefined },
     'volAddressCoords.type':
      { ValidatorError: `,` is not a valid enum value for path `volAddressCoords.type`.
        message: '`,` is not a valid enum value for path `volAddressCoords.type`.',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'enum',
        path: 'volAddressCoords.type',
        value: [Object] } },
  message: 'User validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
```

i also tried this code as mentioned in another SO question [Does applying a 2dsphere index on a mongoose schema force the location field to be required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388836/does-applying-a-2dsphere-index-on-a-mongoose-schema-force-the-location-field-to) but the same error occurs:

```
UserSchema.pre('patch', function (next) {
  if (this.isNew && Array.isArray(this.volAddressCoords) && 0 === this.volAddressCoords.length) {
    this.volAddressCoords = undefined;
  }
  next();
});
```

What can i do in order to work?

Answer (score 0):

my bad, i was casting object to a string...

```
volAddressCoords: {type: Object,
    properties: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        enum: 'Point',
        default: 'Point'
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        default: [0, 0]
      },
      index: {type: String, default: '2dsphere'}
    }}
```

Comment: Can you share the correct syntax of resolving this issue ?

Comment: Sorry @MuhammadUsama but this project is way old and lots of things has changed since then. What problem are you facing exactly?